# Table structure for featured post / featured article etc

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I wanted to ask what's a decent way to implement a featured post or featured article. In some blogs, you set a post as featured based on your own choosing and the last from the existing list gets replaced; I wish to do the same.

Say I have a table entitled **Posts** with the following columns: post_id, post_message, post_date, user_who_posted, category (i.e. Art, Film).

I'm choosing between these 2 ideas, but they may be inappropriate:

1. Create a column on the same table entitled "Type" with value either
   Null or Featured.
2. Create a column on the same table entitled
   "Featured" with value either 1 or 0.

If one of the two above is appropriate, it'll post a bit of a dilemma because there may be a scenario where I may want an older article to be at the #1 place of the featured list over the newer ones. If so, would it make sense to create another column to track the date and time when I set them as featured? What'll happen is that I'll just set the older article featured again or featured last to be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the two approaches is recommended.

If you create a column called `Type` it will be ambiguous and the values difficult to track.
If you create a column called `Featured` the column has a well-defined meaning, but the values are not very useful. Why 0 or 1?

The best option in such requirements is to create a column called `Featured` of type `Datetime` and make it nullable. If the value is NULL then you know the post is not featured. If multiple posts are featured, you can show only the most recently featured ones. If you need to put an older featured post up on top, just give it a fresh date.

Answer (score 1):

"Appropriate" is subjective, but if you want a quick and easy way of doing this, you could have another attribute in the posts table titled `featured_order` which would be an integer, and then you could query according to whether a post is `featured`, and order by the `featured_order` attribute.

Something like:

`` SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `featured` = 1 ORDER BY `featured_order` ASC; ``

Note that `featured_order` should be nullable.

You can then set the older post with a lower `featured_order` than a newer post which is also featured, but has a higher `featured_order` value.

Hopefully that makes sense.

The reason I prefer integers for this type of functionality is it's a lot easier (for us humans) to figure out which is higher/lower in the order when compared to a DATETIME attribute, and setting the order is also easier.

Answer (score 0):

Neither -- Make another table.

This table would have a link to the featured article(s), plus ordering info, but not much else.

This way, all manipulation of "featured" is in this extra table, and only in this extra table.